# Pundit authorisation using service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, authorization, pundit

**The Tools**

1. [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) Authorisation; experimenting with [this pull request](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/pull/136) linked to from the official Pundit README;
2. [ActiveInteraction](http://devblog.orgsync.com/active_interaction/) domain service objects ("DSOs");
3. RSpec 2.99.1

** The Project**

The project repo is on Github; what's under scrutiny here is on the [`pundit-1` branch](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/tree/pundit-1).

I've followed the Pundit tutorial and gotten authorisation working using "traditional" chubby controllers; see

- [the `PostsController#new` action](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb#L43-L92) and [its spec](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb#L43-L92);
- [the Pundit `ApplicationPolicy` class](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/app/policies/application_policy.rb); and
- [the `PostDataPolicy`](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/app/policies/post_data_policy.rb) governing authorisation for the Rails model instances of Posts.

All well and good so far. And then we come to the `SessionController`, whose `#new` and `#destroy` actions respectively govern logging in and out..

The [current code](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb) and [spec](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb) Work Just Fine using traditional-ish controller logic (see how `#new` calls [private methods](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb#L84-L88) that use Pundit to authorise the active (current) user using a [`SessionDataPolicy`](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/app/policies/session_data_policy.rb).

Then I try to encapsulate that logic within an [ActiveInteraction DSO](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb) (see the [commented-out code](https://github.com/jdickey/new_poc/blob/pundit-1/spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb) in `SessionsController#new`), and all hell breaks loose.

More specifically, the version of the `SessionsController` spec [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jdickey/371195b61a243b2ff1c3) raises a `Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError` at the point where the spec calls the `#new` method.

**Whiskey. Tango. FOX?!?!?**

Has *anybody* been able to get similar code working *without* Pundit living directly inside the controller code, ideally using [@billychan's pull request](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/pull/136) (a better alternate will be gratefully entertained)?

This has me *completely* flummoxed.

Comment: The links to the pundit-1 branch and controllers above are both returning 404's (potentially private repo?). That is making it difficult for me to tell what is going on exactly.

Comment: Sorry about that, John. The repo is still there and public; the branch has been deleted, apparently by one of my 'helpful' collaborators. I can't find out more since GitHub doesn't apparently support activity reports going back farther than a month, and I don't have the branch locally anymore, either.

This is old enough now that I probably really ought to just delete the question, since _everything_ about it is outdated now. I'll leave it up a little while longer just so you can get this. Sorry again.

Comment: Jeff Dickey, For someone starting with Service Objects, do you have a recommendation of how to implement path/activity based authorization. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: @user553620 can you just use the class instantiation like `PolicyName.new(user, context).action?`

Answer (score 1):

`Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError` is raised because of `#verify_authorized` method that is basically checking for `@_pundit_policy_authorized` variable.

You can just turn off verification for controllers that don't need it.

UPD. and again necroposting. I need to pay more attention to dates :\

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HeadLess policy at DSOs level like

```
Struct.new(:user)
```

and then validate methods authorisation on users.